# Fractional Sobolev regularity of the solution to the fractional Dirichlet problem on a ball

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, fractional-sobolev-spaces

While reading some [notes](https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/%7Emfaustmann/?id=NonLoc) due to Markus Faustmann, I came across the following exercise regarding the fractional Dirichlet problem on the unit ball.

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(-\Delta)^\alpha u &= f, && \text{on } B_1(0), \\
u &= 0, && \text{on } \mathbb{R}^N \setminus B_1(0),
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
where the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
(-\Delta)^\alpha u(x) := C(N,\alpha) \, \text{P.V.} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{\vert x-y \vert^{N+2\alpha}} \, dy,
\end{equation*}
and $f \equiv 2^{2\alpha} \Gamma(1 + \alpha)^2$.

Exercise 5.3 of the linked notes indicates we have the following solution to the above problem
\begin{equation*}
u(x) = (1 - \vert x \vert^2)_+^\alpha, \qquad g_+:= \max\{g,0\},
\end{equation*}
and it has the following Sobolev regularity
\begin{equation}
u \in H^{\alpha + \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon}(B_1(0)), \qquad\forall \, \varepsilon > 0,
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
u \notin H^{\alpha + \frac{1}{2}}(B_1(0)).
\end{equation}

I'm trying to show the above two inclusions. It is clear that $u \in L^2(B_1(0))$ since $u$ and the domain are bounded.  What remains is to show the Sobolev-Slobodeckij seminorm $\vert u\vert_{H^\theta(B_1(0))}$ is finite for $\theta \in (-\infty, \alpha + \frac{1}{2})$, where
\begin{equation*}
\vert u \vert_{H^{\theta}(B_1(0))}^2 := \int_{B_1(0)} \int_{B_1(0)} \frac{(u(x) - u(y))^2}{\vert x - y \vert^{N + 2\theta}} \,dy \, dx
\end{equation*}

The result is clear when $N + 2\theta \le 0$, which corresponds to $\theta \in (-\infty, -\frac{N}{2}]$.  Also, using $u \in C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{B_1(0)})$, we can extend to the case $-N - 2(\theta - \alpha) > -1$, i.e., $\theta \in (-\infty, -\frac{N}{2} + \alpha + \frac{1}{2})$. Unfortunately, neither of these observations are particularly useful, since the weak formulation of the problem guarantees that $u \in \tilde{H}^\alpha(B_1(0))$.

Can somebody provide some guidance on how to proceed with showing $u \in H^{\alpha + \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon}(B_1(0)) \setminus H^{\alpha + \frac{1}{2}}(B_1(0))$ for $\varepsilon > 0$?  Thank you!

Comment: Is $f$ a constant or is that a typo in the question? Also, what is $g$?

Comment: You’re correct, $f$ is a constant, the one specified above. Also, $g$ is just a dummy argument for the “positive part” function, so the positive part of $g$ is $g_+ := \max\{x, 0\}$. In this context, the positive part is just used to truncate the function $ 1-\vert x\vert^2$ on the exterior of the unit ball.